# Lodash sort collection based on external array

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array with keys like so:

```
['asdf12','39342aa','12399','129asg',...]
```

and a collection which has these keys in each object like so:

```
[{guid: '39342aa', name: 'John'},{guid: '129asg', name: 'Mary'}, ... ]
```

Is there a fast way to sort the collection based on the order of keys in the first array?

Comment: what are language you used?

Comment: I am using javascript

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
var sortedCollection = _.sortBy(collection, function(item){
  return firstArray.indexOf(item.guid)
});
```

Comment: @silintzir You asked for `a fast way to sort the collection` in the question. But this is not a fast way, if you really meant the runtime performance.

Comment: This works perfectly and is the most elegant solution I have found

Comment: simple solution!

Comment: does it keep the elements of collection that match with no element from first array or deletes them ?

Comment: What is the most effective way to do sorting based on multiple keys?

Comment: This is ok, except if the an item isn't on the ordering array it appears first.

Comment: @RobertMoskal It's a bit more verbose, but here's a relatively clean fix to that:

  `_.sortBy(collection, (item) => {

    const index = firstArray.indexOf(item.guid);
    return index === -1 ? Infinity : index;

  });`

Answer (score 16):

Here is just a simple add to the accepted answer in case you want to put the unmatched elements at the end of the sortedCollection and not at the beginning:

```
const last = collection.length;

var sortedCollection = _.sortBy(collection, function(item) {
  return firstArray.indexOf(item.guid) !== -1? firstArray.indexOf(item.guid) : last;
});
```

Comment: Even though this wasn't the accepted answer, to me it is, as it seems more natural to put the unknown elements at the end of the array, after all the sorted items, instead of the beginning

Answer (score 11):

**Input:**

```
var data1 = ['129asg', '39342aa'];
var data2 = [{
    guid: '39342aa',
    name: 'John'
}, {
    guid: '129asg',
    name: 'Mary'
}];
```

1. First create an index object, with `_.reduce`, like this

   ```
   var indexObject = _.reduce(data2, function(result, currentObject) {
       result[currentObject.guid] = currentObject;
       return result;
   }, {});
   ```
2. And then `map` the items of the first array with the objects from the `indexObject`, like this

   ```
   console.log(_.map(data1, function(currentGUID) {
       return indexObject[currentGUID]
   }));
   ```

**Output**

```
[ { guid: '129asg', name: 'Mary' },
  { guid: '39342aa', name: 'John' } ]
```

**Note:** This method will be very efficient if you want to sort so many objects, because it will reduce the linear look-up in the second array which would make the entire logic run in O(M * N) time complexity.

Comment: I really like this answer, however it doesn't cover cases when there are multiple elements with the same guid. Just pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is the efficient & clean way:

(Import lodash `identity` and `sortBy`):

**TS**:

```
function sortByArray<T, U>({ source, by, sourceTransformer = identity }: { source: T[]; by: U[]; sourceTransformer?: (item: T) => U }) {
  const indexesByElements = new Map(by.map((item, idx) => [item, idx]));
  const orderedResult = sortBy(source, (p) => indexesByElements.get(sourceTransformer(p)));
  return orderedResult;
}
```

Or in **JS**:

```
function sortByArray({ source, by, sourceTransformer = _.identity }) {
    const indexesByElements = new Map(by.map((item, idx) => [item, idx]));
    const orderedResult = _.sortBy(source, (p) => indexesByElements.get(sourceTransformer(p)));
    return orderedResult;
}
```

Comment: I really like this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [indexBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#indexBy), and [at()](https://lodash.com/docs#at) to sort your collection. The advantage being that concise code and performance. Using `sortBy()` here does the trick, but your external array is *already* sorted:

```
var ids = [ 'cbdbac14', 'cf3526e2', '189af064' ];

var collection = [
    { guid: '189af064', name: 'John' },
    { guid: 'cf3526e2', name: 'Julie' },
    { guid: 'cbdbac14', name: 'James' }
];

_(collection)
    .indexBy('guid')
    .at(ids)
    .pluck('name')
    .value();
// → [ 'James', 'Julie', 'John' ]
```

Using `at()`, you can iterate over the sorted external collection, building a new collection from the source `collection`. The source collection has been transformed into an object using `indexBy()`. You do this so at() has key-based access for each of it's `ids`.

Comment: this answer should be updated as the lodash way and functions has changed.