# Trying to update a table with sorted values using Lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, lodash

Trying to update a table with sorted values using Lodash. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719795/lodash-sort-collection-based-on-external-array) answer, which I am trying to implement.

Demo plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SIjyUH0ZaYxYw1Y3UIHv?p=preview) - outputting sorted values to console when you click on the 'Sort' button, but does not sort and update the table values (`vm.resourceGridResources.Resources`) afterwards?

Code:

```
var sorted = _.orderBy(results, ['Value'], ['asc']);

console.log(sorted);

//this part is not working...
var sortedCollection = _.sortBy(temp, function(item) {
    return sorted.indexOf(item.ResourceId);
});

vm.resourceGridResources.Resources = sortedCollection;
```

Please can you advise how to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `.indexOf` on array with objects. You can use [findIndex](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#findIndex) from lodash:

```
_.findIndex(sorted, {ResourceId: item.ResourceId});
```