# How to sort an array containing another array using lodash?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting, lodash

I've been trying to sort an array by a value within a nested array, data.Count.  Unfortunately, I cannot seem to access it with lodash sortBy.  Is there a better way to approach this?

```
 example = () => {
   const exampleArray = [];


   _.forEach(this.state.example[name], (data) => {
       exampleArray.push({name, data });
   })

    // these logs all work fine
    console.log(exampleArray); 
    console.log(exampleArray[0]);
    console.log(exampleArray[0].data.count); // prints out 4

    //****console error: data is undefined
    _.sortBy(exampleArray, [name, data.count]);

    return exampleArray
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lodash sort collection based on external array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719795/lodash-sort-collection-based-on-external-array)

Comment: not an external array.  I'm trying to sort an array by a specific attribute which is contained inside yet another array object which is still contained into the overall array.